# Tapestry jquery confirm dialog not working

Tags: jquery, dialog, tapestry

I am trying to use confirmation dialog in Tapestry using jquery. I have just inserted this code in my tml page and it's not working.

```
 <t:pagelink t:id="pageLinkConfirm" page="index"
t:useDefaultConfirm="true" t:message="Return to Index?"
t:mixins="jquery/Confirm">PageLink confirmation test</t:pagelink>
```

When I click on the page link dialog opens, but when I click on OK button it doesn't return index page. It does the same thing like Cancel button, just hides confirm dialog. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a dialog, like this:

```
<t:jquery.dialog t:clientId="dialogId" t:id="dialogId" 
title="confirm" style="display: none;">
            <t:submit value="submit" />
            <t:eventlink event="cancel" id="btnCancel" async="true">
            Cancel</t:eventlink>
</t:jquery.dialog>
```

After make a js on the pagelink, what triggers the dialog, and make a trigger on the cancel button, what will close the dialog.

js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var confirmDialog = $("#dialogId");
    var dialogClose = $("#btnCancel");
    var confirmLink = $("#pageLinkConfirm");

    dialogClose.click(function() {
        confirmDialog.dialog("close");
    });


    confirmLink.click(function() {
        confirmDialog.dialog("open");
    });
});
```

I know it is not the prettiest solution, but it could work.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a fix for the confirm mixin. Use version 3.4.1 (https://github.com/got5/tapestry5-jquery/releases).